# Как подключить GitHub к проекту Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, контроль-версий

Я создаю новый проект в Android Studio.
Что мне следует сделать, чтобы все изменения из AS коммитились на ГитХаб? Или как правильно подключить любую другую систему контроля версий?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Лично я считаю [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) более предпочтительным GitHub , так как условия там несколько лучше, в частности бесплатные приватные репозитории.

**Инструкция, как подключить уже существующий проект BitBucket или GitHub**:

Далее инструкция для Bitbucket, практически то же самое нужно проделать и для клонирования репозитория с GitHub (кроме настройки плагина - в данном случае это будет плагин GitHub)

1. Устанавливаем на компьютер программу [Git](http://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. Настраиваем Git в AS (*File - Settings... - Version Control - Git* : Указываем путь до *git.exe* и жмем кнопку Test , чтобы убедиться , что все работает )
3. Ставим в AS плагин bitbuket ( *File - Settings... - Plugins : Browse repositories* ) - в общем то его можно и не ставить . Практическую пользу , кроме того , что появляется пункт : *VCS - Import into Version Control - Share project...* уловить не удалось - это нужно для того , чтобы "залить" локальный проект на BitBucket - если ваш случай , то ставьте , если проект уже есть в репозитории , то можно воздержаться .
4. Если установили плагин , настраиваем bitbucket в AS ( *File - Settings... - Bitbucket* : пишем логин и пароль к своему репозиторию и нажимаем кнопку Test , чтобы убедиться , что всё всё еще работает )
5. Клонируем проект из репозитория на компьютер . *VCS - Checkout from Version Control - Git* ( не bitbucket ни в коем случае - этот пункт есть , если ставили плагин , но нажимать его не надо , он все равно не работает ) : пишем в строке "Vcs repository URL" HTTPS-адрес ( не SSH ) своего репозитория ( получить можно на странице "Обзор" вашего проекта в BitBucket - кнопка SSH в верхнем правом углу - нажимаем и переключаем на HTTPS ) - нажимаем Test , вводим пароль от аккаунта BitBucket , затем придумываем мастер-пароль на хранилище паролей в IDE  - если вокруг не крутятся враги , можно просто нажать OK и убеждаемся , что всё всё еще работает . В полях ниже выбираем куда клонировать проект и название папки проекта
6. Нажимаем Clone
7. После некоторых манипуляций загрузки появиться окошко с вопросом , не надо ли открыть вновь обретенный проект - соглашаемся .

Проект на bitbucket синхронизируется с локальным репозиторием *git* , можно продолжать работу над давно забытым проектом .
Практически то же самое (кроме настройки плагина - в данном случае это будет плагин GitHub)  нужно проделать и для клонирования репозитория с *GitHub*

**Подключение нового проекта к GitHub**:

1. Вам нужно так же сначала установить сам Git, как в пункте 1 выше и указать путь до него в IDE (пункт 2)
2. Обычно плагин *GitHub* уже установлен в IDE, если это не так его нужно установить в настройках в разделе *Plugins*
3. Заполнить логин\пароль к аккаунту *GitHub* в настройках (если аккаунта нет, его предварительно нужно зарегестрировать): *VersionControl ->GitHub*
4. выбрать: *VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub* и следовать предложениям мастера.

**Подключение нового репозитория BitBucket**:

1. Все так же сначала нужно установить сам Git, как в пункте 1 в начале и указать путь до него в IDE (пункт 2)
2. Ставим в AS плагин bitbuket ( *File - Settings... - Plugins : Browse repositories* )
3. Заполнить логин\пароль к аккаунту *BitBucket* в настройках (если аккаунта нет, его предварительно нужно зарегистрировать)
4. Выбрать *VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Share Project ..* и следовать предложениям мастера.

PS: способы выгодно отличается от геморроя с SSH ключами , командными строками git и прочими сомнительными радостями "классического" клонирования .

PPS:клонировать существующий репозиторий можно из окна начального старта ( когда ни один проект не открыт ) проследовав сначала в раздел *Configure - Settings* ( для настройки git ) , затем в *Checkout project from Version Control - Git*

**UPD: Сохранение изменений в локальный и удаленный репозиторий**

Вся дальнейшая работа с локальным и удаленным репозиторием производится в разделе VCS основного меню Android Studio.
Например, для того, чтобы внести изменения в проекте в локальный и\или удаленный репозиторий (GitHub) нужно проделать следующую манипуляцию:

1. Какие-то изменения должны существовать в проекте со времени последнего коммита в репозиторий, иначе новый коммит не пройдет. Либо, если только пушить на удаленный репозиторий (GitHub), то должен быть еще незапушенный коммит.
2. Выбираем: *VCS ->  Commit Changes ..*
3. Появляется окно, в котором мы видим файлы проекта с изменениями, здесь можно выбрать, какие файлы должны попасть в коммит, а какие - нет (галочки). По умолчанию выбраны все, где были какие то изменения со времени последнего коммита - все попадут в репозиторий. Для коммита необходимо написать комментарий к нему (Commit Message), так же можно установить дополнительные параметры по коду, справа.
4. Теперь для завершения операции вам нужно нажать на кнопку внизу, которая подписана *Commit* - эта кнопка скрывает три варианта действия:

   а. *Commit* - изменения в проекте будут добавлены только в локальный репозиторий (commit). Отправить в удаленный репозиторий можно позже, командой *VCS -> Git -> Push*

   b. *Commit and Push* - помимо локального репозитория, изменения будут добавлены (push) и в удаленный репозиторий (GitHub)

   c. Create Patch - сделать патч. на нем останавливаться не будем.

Файлы в окне проекта слева (Project Explorer) будут окрашены [следующим образом](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html), сигнализируя о состоянии по отношению к системе VCS.

Comment: спасибо огромное, Добрый Человек! Дай Бог здоровья! Поставил я BitBucket, но дочитав до конца мне хватило этой строчки VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub . Вроде все отправилось на ГитХаб. И есть там репозиторий, но я не вижу самих фалов и кода. Буду дальше голову ломать и внимательно перечитывать Ваш солюшн.

Comment: В случае GitHub, вроде, ничего больше не требуется - Share .. и все, проект там. У вас локальный Git установлен, подключен в IDE и откликается на "Test" ?

Comment: да, конечно. Установлен и тестится. На ГитХабе даже создался репозиторий, но он пустой. Имя репозитория == имя моего проекта

Comment: Ура! Вопрос решен. Проект на Гитхабе. Теперь буду учиться пользоваться этим добром. Спасибо за исчерпывающую информацию!!! :)

Comment: @UnknownPerson дополнил немного по работе. Остальное смотрите, как вообще работать с системой git, там бывает довольно заморочно все.

Comment: @pavlofff благодарю за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Для этого вам надо :

1. [создать репозиторий на GitHub'e](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)
2. [Инициировать](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F) репозиторий в существующем проекте
3. Выполнить команду [git remote add [сокращение] [url]](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2)

После успешного выполнения этих комманд можно комитить изменения в локальном репозитории и отправлять их на удаленный сервер при помощи команды [git push [удал. сервер] [ветка]](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8#Push)

Все команды выполняются в интерпретаторе команд Git Bash, который устанавливается вместе с Git.

В Android Studio это можно выполнить так:

1. VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration, выбрать там Git
2. VCS -> Git -> Push. В появившемся окне выбрать Define Remote. Но сначала надо сделать хотя бы 1 commit.
   [image]
3. В появившемся окне ввести имя удаленного репозитория и ссылку на него. После чего будет подключен удаленный репозиторий.

Чтобы изменения отправлять на сервер GitHub надо в Android Studio выбирать VCS -> Commit Changes или комбинация клавиш Ctrl + K и поменять Commit на Commit And Push, либо делать отдельно commit и отдельно push

Comment: Проект на ГитХабе. Спасибо огромное Вам за помощь))))))

Comment: Добавлю, что это решение подходит для другого Git-сервера. Моем случаем Bonobo.Git.Server. Достаточно прописать удаленный репозиторий и IDE прекрасно работает с ним.