# Доступ к git по ssh через ключ

Tags: git, ssh, intellij-idea

Как можно настроить git с ключом на Intellije IDEA, сейчас работает по логину и паролю.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, настроить нужно не IDEA, а удаленный репозиторий - дать ему ваш публичный ключ.

Comment: В *IntelliJ IDEA* нет инструментов для настройки *git* на работу через SSH-ключ. Все делается через консоль и Git Bash - настройкой репозитория к которому подключен проект.

Comment: @pavlofff как можно это настроить, в документации говорится надо добавить .pub в authorized_keys но что надо сделать на клиенте, не гооворитс

Comment: В свое (уже довольно давнее) время я отказался от авторизации через SSH в пользу HTTPS из-за излишней сложности подключения и настройки в IDE. Как настроить для работы по HTTPS [смотрите этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345), если вас интересует такой вариант.

Comment: нет, такое не интересует, мне нужно только по SSH, не я решаю

Comment: Ещё актуально? Скажите, какая у вас ОС, для начала. )

Comment: Да еще актуально, Я использую windows 7, intellij idea 14.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую Pageant, поэтому ключ загружаю в нем и потом уже в IDEA для репозитория в настройках ставлю использовать нативный SSH.
File->Settings->Version Control->Git->SSH executable: Native
Для встроенного SSH я не нашел, где указывать ключик (при этом в настройках SVN сразу видно куда свой ключ вписывать)
P.S. IDEA вроде как через системную переменную свой клиент настраивает.