# Клонировать проект

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

Есть проект на Bitbucket.org, пытаюсь его склонировать к себе на домашний комп(по нажатию кнопку Test пишет что подключился к данному репозиторию), но файлы не клонируются.
(Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение).
Но переходя в Project файлы есть, увы не могу запустить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, что у вас файлы не указаны как исходники. Попробуйте покопаться в настройках проекта и проверить, что у вас gradle файлы скачались

Comment: Ну в build.gradle выделяет используемые мною библиотеки:
'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'.
А папка External libraires вообще пустая...

Comment: Иногда помогает перезапуск студии. и/или импортирование проекта в студию из папки где он лежит

Comment: возможно эта [инструкция](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345) по подключению репозитория вам поможет.

Comment: а вручную из консоли получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Проект был у меня на linux'e(это как ремарка)
- Ребятам на будущее посоветовал бы закидывать некоторые файлы в [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore)

  Со временем вы сами наработаете себе этот файл.
- Для Android Studio неплохой этот вариант 
  [gitignore Android Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore)

  Здесь все файлы, которые Вам не пригодятся на удаленном репозитории.
- Как дополнительный вариант можете установить плагин .gitignore в самой студии.

При переносе проекта с bitbucket'a на машину с ОС Windows выдал сообщение, об удалении 2-ух файлов(**нужно** удалить, также предложит сохранить). После этого *возможно* потребует скачать необходимую версию SDK, у меня запросил 24.0.2 - тут у всех по разному, зависит от Вашего проекта. После этого файлы .gradle скачались и проект собственно запустился.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новую папку и склонируйте заново.
Должно решить проблему.

Comment: пробовал, не выходит(

Comment: через консоль попробуйте. git clone url-project-source