# Ошибка "fatal: Authentication failed" при отправке команды push на Bitbucket

Tags: git, авторизация, bitbucket, репозиторий

Возможно, но видимо что то упустил "на ночь глядя", ну или просто давно не работал с Bitbucket'ом.

Коротко о моих действиях:
создал репозиторий на Bitbucket, после чего совершил действия описанные в "I'm starting from scratch", но после **push**'a выбило следующую ошибку:

```
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party
service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://VadimMorozov@bitbucket.org/VadimMorozo
```

Хочу заметить что до этого был вообще:

```
Could not read from remote repository.
```

Но изменил в ссылке на `https` и вот собственно проблема. Подскажите как быть.

Comment: Изменил повторно пароль, теперь при пуше выбивает диалоговое окно с логином и паролем, ввожу всё верно, ошибка та же.

Comment: Возможно [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345) вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

`https://VadimMorozov@bitbucket.org/VadimMorozov` - это ещё не весь путь к репозиторию. Не хватает собственно названия репозитория:

```
https://VadimMorozov@bitbucket.org/VadimMorozov/project-name.git
```

Давайте его настроим:

```
git remote set-url origin https://VadimMorozov@bitbucket.org/VadimMorozov/project-name.git
```