# Не могу выложить проект на гитхаб

Tags: git, android-studio

Какой то бред. Не понимаю как из студии выкинуть проект на гитхаб. Добавляю все в vcs и делаю share. Но проекта нет, какие то

idea
gradle/wrapper
И всякие другие файлы

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Думаю [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444771/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-github-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-android-studio/444780#444780) вы найдет свой ответ.

Comment: Поскольку последовательность действий по расшариванию проекта на гитхаб включает несколько этапов и в своем вопросе вы никак не уточняете что именно делаете, то угадать почему у вас не получается весьма затруднительно. Для начала исключим очевидные ошибки, скажите, вы в точности выполняете все пункты [данной инструкции](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444771/Как-подключить-github-к-проекту-android-studio/444780#444780)?

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался)) А как увеличить шансы что другие разработчики заметят проект?

Comment: @СергейГрушин, сначала надо сделать его полезным, а потом написать о нём на хабр и/или другие ресурсы

Comment: @СергейГрушин, варитесь *в теме*, делайте полезные штуки, будьте узнаваемы в сообществе -- заметят. У меня друг вон в Майкрософте так на работу устроился, и на нынешний момент там (уже несколько лет).

Comment: @0andriy я думаю, что если человек может сделать такую вещь, чтобы его заметили, то ему в принципе не нужно куда-то устраиваться, потому что он может работать на себя, а не на дядю в виде Майкрософта или еще кого-то.

Comment: @abg, зависит от человека. Я разных встречал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну попробуйте из Git Bash тогда:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/project.git
$ git push origin master:master
```

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Блин как все непонятно..

Comment: @СергейГрушин ну так у Вас даже еще репозитория нет - не создан. Перейдите в папке с проектом и дайте команду git init для того чтобы создать репозиторий.

Comment: Почитал туториалы, книги по гитхабу теперь разобрался в нем) прикольно что работа с ним идёт через командную строку)

Comment: @СергейГрушин, есть немало хороших графических оболочек, например, SourceTree.