# Перенос проекта из GitHub в BitBucket

Tags: git, android-studio, github, bitbucket

Есть проект, который подключен через Android Studio к GitHub. Этот проект нужно убрать из общего поля зрения, поэтому появилась необходимость перевести его на BitBucket.
Можно конечно через Git Bash залить весь репозиторий на BitBucket, что я и сделал.
Но как мне теперь этот проект настроить, чтобы все коммиты он отправлял не на GitHub,а на BitBucket через Android Studio?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git remote set-url origin <clone url репозитория с bitbucket>
```