# Bitbucket и IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

Как использовать Bitbucket в IntelliJ IDEA 2017? Плагин Bitbucket Linky не работает на этой версии.

Comment: Может пригодиться. Видео, как зашарить проект на битбакет
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz5-TimqC9Y

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте плагин Git Integration. В [официальной документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html) подробно описано как его настроить.

Comment: Получаю ошибку 'Push was rejected' и никаких дополнительных пояснений или кода ошибки.

Comment: @VladDogadaev попробуйте выполнить операцию из командной строки и/или посмотрите в логе ошибки.

Comment: @VladDogadaev плюс к Михаилу. Именно из-за этих ошибок без кодов и пояснений рациональнее всего использовать консоль.

Comment: @NickVolynkin  на самом деле, оказывается, подробное описание выводится, но в отдельном терминале Version Control, а в общем только заголовок ошибки.
Как раз из этого описания и узнал, что было не так. Я создал репозиторий с README, а нужен был чистый.