# Как в Андроид Студио под Windows подключить Git?

Tags: android, android-studio, git

Как в Андроид Студио подключить Git?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **Windows**:

1. Если **Git** не установлен, то устанавливаем **Git** [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/download) (в папку по умолчанию) (в режиме Администратора, если что-то пойдет не так)
2. В Андроид-Студии:

> File > Settings > Plugins > **Git Integration** (Ставим галочку)
>
> File > Settings > Version Control > Git > **Test** (Убеждаемся что
>   все норм, иначе правим путь и убеждаемся, что все норм)
>
> VCS > Import into Version Control > **Create Git Repository**
>   (Подтверждаем/создаем папку под Git репозиторий)

3. Внизу экрана появится вкладка **Version Control** (Наслаждаемся контролем кода)

P.S. Для инфо: **Git** - программа, которая создает репозитории, **Github** - это сайт, где можно их хранить (а можно и не хранить)

Comment: Если в постановке вопроса вы пишете, что гит уже установили, зачем тут инструкция по установке?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Он установился на комп нормально Но еще не подключен был к Андроид Студио Здесь описано как подключить его к Андроид Студио

Comment: Я про первый пункт инструкции.

Comment: Ок! Подправил для ясности вопрос и ответ )

Answer (score 4):

В **Mac**:

В AS путь прописывается для Git в настройках:

> Preferences  ->  Version Control  ->  Git  ->  Patch to Git executable

Там же можно протестировать его доступность.

Comment: Там не надо ничего вручную настраивать, среда сама находит гит по стандартному пути.

Comment: @NickVolynkin прочитайте вопрос в изначальном варианте, тогда мой ответ станет более очевидным. И вопросы и ответы были многократно изменены автором вопроса, поменяв в корне смысл.