# Как коммитить и пушить в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Как пользоваться `git` из Idea IDE? Я создал новый инициализированный репозиторий на гитхабе, включил поддержку git в IDEA, в `remotes` добавил новый `origin`, взятый из информации о моем репозитории, закоммитил все нужные файлы, но когда выбираю в меню `git->push`, вижу только список  `master->empty repository` и неактивную кнопку `push`.

Как с этим работать? Не хочу, работая в IDE, постоянно использовать консоль для коммтов.

Comment: У jetbrains есть [статья](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html) на этот счет

Comment: Если кнопка `push` не активна, то вы не можете отправлять изменения на удаленный репозиторий. Возможно потому, что вы добавляли ручками в удаленное хранилище и поэтому наделали там ошибок.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345

Comment: там терминал есть, даже встроенный....

Answer (score 0):

File->Settings->Git есть поле Protected brunches, там скорей всего указан master.
Можно еще проверить в меню VCS->Git->Remotes, что корректно добавился репозиторий.

Создайте бранч в локальном репозитории, работайте в нем, сделайте пуш из этой ветки и потом можно сделать pull-реквест в master на сайте.

Чтобы ничего не ломать "ручками", лучше создавать репозиторий и клонировать его в IDEA File->New->Project from Version Control->Git, далее создавать ветку например "dev" и работать в ней