# Как загрузить проект из git на другом компьютере через android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, git

У меня есть на одном ноутбуке мой проект, который подвязан к репозиторию git. Вот я хочу на другом ноутбуке загрузить этот проект средствами android studio что-бы работать. Можно ли это как-то сделать. У меня есть адрес репозитория и все.

Comment: Еще три года назад писал [инструкция по подключению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345) :)

Comment: @pavlofff, мне лучше вопрос удалить, я так понимаю?))) или пусть два вопроса будет?

Comment: конечно пусть будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не спорю, я задал возможно тупой вопрос, но я столкнулся с такой проблемой впервые, и надеюсь что мой вопрос-ответ поможет таким же начинающим как и я.

Перед тем как загружать проект нужно сделать одну важную вещь - установить Git на свой компьютер. Загружал я установщик с [этого сайта](https://git-scm.com/). После того как `Git` будет установлен, нужно указать в настройках `Android Studio` путь к файлу `git.exe`. Вот как это можно сделать:
[image: изображение]

Ну а теперь, можно переходить непосредственно к импорту проекта из репозитория.

Для того что-бы импортировать свой проект с репозитория нужно перейти на стартовый экран `Android Studio` и выбрать пункт меню как указано на рисунке:
[image: 2]

после нажатия у вас появится список с системами контроля версий (Git, Google Cloud, Mercurial и тд.). Лично мне нужен был Git, поэтому я его и выбрал.

При выборе своей системы контроля версий, у меня высветилось окошко для подключения к репозиторию:

[image: 5].

В указанных полях нужно ввести путь к репозиторию, путь к папке куда вы хотите сохранить проект и название папки будущего проекта. Так как у вас будет первое подключение со студии к удаленному репозиторию, то вам культурно предложат ввести пароль, который я лично сохранил в памяти студии для дальнейшего использования. После этого, на ваш компьютер будет загружен проект. После окончания загрузки вам предложат открыть проект который вы загрузили.

Надеюсь что мой ответ поможет людям с подобной ситуацией. Удачи)