# подключение проекта из github к android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создал проект на android studio и добавил в github через git, окно android studio изменилась след. образом, как настроить android studio чтобы я мог работать с проектом?

Comment: А что, собственно, мешает работать?

Comment: как мне полностью открыть проект? чтобы я мог добавлять иконки в окно и т.п.

Comment: Вы похоже с бранчами запутались. Проект добавили в develop, а открыт у вас master (справа внизу).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345