# git зачем и что это?

Tags: git

Я начинающий разработчик и мне сегодня, на собеседовании по телефону, сказали что отправят тестовое задание и спросили установлен ли у меня git и Android Studio. Android Studio я понимаю конечно, но не понял на счет git зачем это и что это?

Comment: Почитайте статью о [git на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). Если вкратце, это система контроля версий. Позволяет контролировать вносимые в проект изменения, а так же, при необходимости возвращаться к более старым (и наоборот) версиям проекта.

Comment: + хранилище кода. Если у вас установлен git - то они предоставят вам ссылку, по которой вы сможете "стянуть" проект/тесты через студию(clone). И таким же способом сможете внести изменения и отправить им результаты(push)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345

Comment: https://githowto.com/ru