# Android Studio и Git hub Как отправить в уже готовый репозиторий?

Tags: android-studio, github

Уже существует готовый, приватный репозиторий. Но когда Я вожу его название в Git Share Project Android Studio радует меня тем, что создает НОВЫЙ НЕ НУЖНЫЙ РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ и отправляет все туда.

P.S. Пока буду пользоваться Git Extensions, он справляется с этой задачей, хоть и чуток костыльно: копирую с его помощью с внешнего нужного мне репозитория на свой пк, создавая привязку, а после и кидаю в созданную директорию файлы проекта и заливаю на прямик.

Comment: что отправить, речь идет о пуше обычном или о чем?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345